# What does the header frame number sequencing in H264 mean?

Tags: java, video, compression, sequence, h.264

I am looping through a list of H264 NAL header slices for a raw H264 file. While looping through, I am printing out the "slice_type" (iframe = I, pframe = P, or bframe = B) and the "frame_num" (number of the frame in the sequence). The sequence is different for each raw H264 file but, as you can see below, each pattern resets the "frame_num" after a certain "frame_num" count. For this sequence, it resets after  "frame_num" 15 then after "frame_num" 10 then 15 then 10 etc etc. The framerate of this particular H264 is 30. There are 44 '0' "frame_num" and 659 total "frame_num" with about 15 '0' for every other type of "frame_num".

Do any of you know what this sequence of "frame_num" means or why it is reseting? I am hypothesising that each reset is half of a video frame but I am not exactly sure.

I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, I,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15, P,0, P,1, P,2, P,3, P,4, P,5, P,6, P,7, P,8, P,9, P,10, P,11, P,12, P,13, P,14, P,15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is for keeping track of the relative order of frames, for cases with reordering (such as with B-frames). It's resetting because it's only a few bits long, so in your case, after 15 it wraps around to 0. Since the receiver knows how many bits it is, it can also know that 0 is the next frame after 15, and given a short window of frames, e.g. 13, 14, 15, 0, 1, 2, it knows what the right order of those frames are.

Additionally, on IDR frames it also restarts from 0, since frames after those don't depend on the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks! By any chance, do you know how to locate signatures or uniqueness in a H.264 bitstream? Like can you tell who encoded the stream by looking and anything inparticular?

Comment: Not really. Some encoders (such as x264) include identification saying what encoder it was, in a SEI NAL (ofteh before the first SPS/PPS), but other than that, there's probably no easy identification. You'd have to look through the bitstream and see what bitstream features different encoders commonly use (iirc weighted prediction is a feature that might not be so common with encoders other than x264).

Comment: Thanks. So the only real form of identification is looking at the features that are activated within the h264 bitstream?

Comment: Yes, and that's of course no guaranteed identification either (a newer version of an encoder could start using a feature it didn't use before), but it's probably the only thing you can use.